# How to find all files a particular user has ever changed in Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs, version-control, tfs-code-review

I know there is an easy way to do this with SVN so there must be a similar way with TFS.

Basically, I want to have a list of every file a particular username ever edited (IE: checked out & changed or added).  This is on TFS 2008.

Comment: You'd better decode what TFS is. Many poeple wouldn't know that it's Team Foundation Server (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/default.aspx)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I found one way to do it:

1. Go to Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio
2. Right click on the project root
3. Select Find in Source Control -> Changesets
4. Enter the username you are looking for in the 'By User' field
5. Click find

This returns a list of changesets from the user.  You can then click the details button to expand the changeset.

Comment: Just rebuilt my machine and noticed that the 'Find in Source Control' option is part of the TFS Power Tools - Oct 2008 package as well.

Comment: To open the “Source Control Explorer”, open the “View” menu, click “Other Windows”, and then click “Source Control Explorer”.

Comment: In case any VS 2013 users make it here, like me, here are the steps:
1. Open Source Control Explorer. 
2. Right click on project root. 
3. Click "Find" -> "Find Changesets". 
4. Enter username in "By user" box. 
5. Click "Find" button.

Answer (score 12):

The answers so far return a list of changesets, not a list of files.  Try:

```
Get-TfsItemHistory $/ -r -user username -all | Select-TfsItem | sort -unique path
```

Using the Powershell cmdlets also included with the [Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Bryan - the answer you provided is one way.  You can also do this in fewer steps by installing the free [Team Foundation Server Power Tools - October 2008 Release](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx) from MSDN.  There are a number of great out-of-band updates to the Team Explorer feature set, but the one you are interested in is called the **Team Members** feature:

[Team Members Node http://img34.imageshack.us/img34/7195/image21k.png](http://img34.imageshack.us/img34/7195/image21k.png)

This will allow you to quickly search for all check-in's by a given Team Member.  Look around at the other features as I am sure you will find some other handy things as well.  Personally, I like the "Show Shelvesets" as it makes it much easier to use the Shelveset feature for code reviews, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I know how to do this in VS2010 and I'm sure it works the very similar in VS 2008 --

In Visual Studio, open "Team Explorer" window.
Expand your main TFS branch.
Expand "Team Members" branch. Under this branch you will see the names of all TFS members.
Right-click a member, and select "Show Checkin History".  This will list all the files changed (checked in) by the selected member.

I hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: In VS 2010 Premium "Team Members" branch isn't available. So for VS 2010 Premium the steps would be **Source Control Explorer** (_View --> Other Windows_) --> Select the Project --> From '**File**' menu --> **Source Control** --> **Find In Changesets**